# How do I update my AWS credentials in order to use S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use AWS S3 to upload files, but right now I need to put in my credentials for my account. I'm unsure how to do this, as other tutorials said to locate a `.aws` folder and find a file called `credentials`, but I cannot find this folder, nor the file, anywhere. What do I need to install, if anything, that will help me out? Am I missing something?

Yes, I already have my access key ID and my secret access key. I'm just not sure where to go from here.

I am using a Mac, if that helps.

Comment: first thing first you need to install AWS CLI. check here for instruction - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html.

you can add credentials by running - `aws configure` in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access aws from your machine, you have to install aws cli in your machine.
The below link helps you to install aws cli.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-mac.html

Once you completed the installation, you have to configure the aws credentials using
`$aws configure

That's it. Try that :)

Comment: Hey, I was able to configure my AWS account as such (although I'm not sure what `Default output format [None]:` so I left that blank, and I entered `Default region name [None]: Global`), but this ended up opening a new problem for me when I tried using boto3 to upload files, which I will post when my cooldown runs out.

Comment: Nevermind to my previous comment - I incorrectly configured my AWS keys through the terminal. Thanks for the help